# what is the length of this array? c language

Tags: c

```
char msg[100] = {’C’,’P’,’R’,‘E’,‘\0’,‘2’,‘8’, ‘8’,‘\0’};
int my_length = 0xFFFFFFFF;
my_length = strlen(msg);
```

I thought it is nine, however, the answer is 4. anyone can explain? thanks

Comment: This question seems somehow the same [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231470/how-to-find-actual-end-of-char-array-in-c-containing-zeros-in-the-middle/33232025#33232025)

Comment: BTW: The *size* of the array is 100. You are asking for the length of the *string*.

Comment: None of those three lines are your problem. You have no idea about strlen. That's the whole problem. Who told you about '\0' and it's usage ?

Comment: _The C library function size_t strlen(const char *str) computes the length of the string str up to, but not including the terminating null character._ `\0` is the _terminating null character_, hence `strlen(msg)` equals 4.

Comment: `’` look like smart quotes and not `'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that in C, a *string* is simply a sequence of character values followed by a zero-valued terminator.  Strings are stored in arrays of `char` (or `wchar_t` for wide strings), but not every array of `char` (or `wchar_t`) is a string.  To store a string that's `N` characters long, you need an array with *at least* `N + 1` elements to account for the terminator.

`strlen` returns the number of characters in the string starting at the specified address up to the zero terminator.

To get the size (in bytes) of the `msg` array, use the `sizeof` operator:

```
char msg[100] = {'C','P','R','E','\0','2','8','8','\0'};    
size_t my_length = strlen( msg );
size_t my_size = sizeof msg;

if ( my_length >= my_size )
  // whoopsie
```

In this case, you're actually storing two strings in one array (`"CPRE"` and `"288"`).

The *size* of the `msg` array is 100 (as given by the declaration).

The length of the *string* `"CPRE"` starting at `msg[0]` is 4, since you have a zero terminator in the fifth element of the array (`'\0' == 0`).

The length of the string `"288"` starting at `msg[5]` is 3 since you have another zero terminator in the ninth element of the array.

Answer (score 4):

`strlen` will stop counting as soon as it hits a null terminator (as C uses null terminated strings and expects to only find them at the end of a string).

You have four characters before your first null terminator, therefore the length is 4.

Answer (score 4):

`strlen` returns 4 because the (first) **string** in `msg` is terminated by the `\0` at `msg[4]`. However, the **array** `msg` has a length of 100 `char`s because it was declared as such.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is typo in your

```
char msg[100] = {’C’,’P’,’R’,‘E’,‘\0’,‘2’,‘8’, ‘8’,‘\0’};
```

and you wanted

```
char msg[100] = {’C’,’P’,’R’,‘E’,‘0’,‘2’,‘8’, ‘8’,‘\0’};
```

(plainly: `CPRE0288`), so binary `0` (instead of the *character representation of 0* , i. e. `'0'`) *prematurely* finishes your string.

Comment: No is not. One is to type 0 another one is to type '\0', for the last one you hit keyboard 4 times. So NO, there was no typo....

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assume that the return value of `strlen` represents the size of an array.

`strlen` will take a pointer to the start of a string and increment the pointer while looking for a null terminator; once it finds that, it returns the counter (i.e. number of increments before the null was found).

You declared `msg` to be of length 100, but only populated 9 elements in the array.  `sizeof(msg)` will be 100.

Are you actually asking "how can I find out how many values are initialized in an array"? There's really no answer to that.

Comment: `msg` is *populated* with 100 bytes, the first 9 of which are explicitly given in the initializer, but the remainder are initialized to 0.

Comment: Yes but the OP's statement that he expected the result to be 9 makes me think he was asking "how do I find out how many array elements were explicitly initialized?", which is not something that we can find out with C code - what if he had a bunch of trailing zeroes in the explicitly initialized variables?